# how to call a php function when we open the page

Tags: php

```
/*the function which fetches data from database */public function allClients()
{
    try
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->query("SELECT * FROM client");
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $results;
    }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

This is the next page where the function is called.I have used a fetch button:'btn-signup' but I want to display this data in a table without using any button how do I do that.

```
$client2 = new client2();
if (isset($_POST['btn-signup'])) 
{  
    try
    {   
            $results=$client2->allClients();

            foreach(array ($results) as $row) 
        {


            $id = $row['id'];
            $name = $row['name'];
            $email = $row['email'];
            echo $id."\t\t";
            echo $name."\t\t";
            echo $email;
            echo "\n\n";

        }

    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

The table in which i need to fetch the values.THANK you

```
<table id="data-table-command" class="table table-striped table-vmiddle">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th data-column-id="id" data-type="numeric">ID</th>
                                    <th data-column-id="sender">Sender</th>
                                    <th data-column-id="received" data-order="desc">Received</th>
                                    <th data-column-id="commands" data-formatter="commands" data-sortable="false">Commands</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                    <td>10238</td>
                                    <td>eduardo@pingpong.com</td>
                                    <td>14.10.2013</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>10243</td>
                                    <td>eduardo@pingpong.com</td>
                                    <td>19.10.2013</td>
                                </tr></tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: you mean , you want to display the values in your tablle (HTML table) when the page loads ? right ?

Comment: i do not see where you place the data into the table with that button. And where is the button?

Comment: i didnt add that button on this page@KristjanKica

Comment: ya right@UsmanRana

Comment: The problem is i dont kn how to use my function to display the fetched values in my table,I am new to PHP@Loko

Comment: @Pihu did it worked? I was about to edit my answer after you posted that error, but you delete your comment..

Answer (score 1):

```
<table id="data-table-command" class="table table-striped table-vmiddle">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th data-column-id="id" data-type="numeric">ID</th>
           <th data-column-id="sender">Sender</th>
           <th data-column-id="received" data-order="desc">Received</th>
           <th data-column-id="commands" data-formatter="commands" data-sortable="false">Commands</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        foreach( array($results) as $row ) 
        {
           echo '<tr>';
           echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
           echo '<td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
           echo '<td>' . $row['email'] . '</td>';
           echo '</tr>';
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You do the `foreach` inside your table printing the vars with the proper table markup

Comment: all the records are getting printed on a single line and the first table row which i changed is only showing "0" for colum id,the rest of the columns are blank

Comment: Okay, I changed my answer and edited only this part `foreach($results as $row) ` .. try it like this.. I don't use to fetch the data like you did, so I'm not sure if it's going to work..

Comment: Thxz for the help bt actually by doing that it will throw me an error ,since $result is not an array so I need to type-cast it

Comment: When I fetch data from the db, I already send it in an array, that's why I suggested that.. Sorry I can't help more :s

Comment: Np you tried your best and i appretiate that I'll try wat u suggested

Answer (score 0):

**change**

```
echo $id."\t\t";
echo $name."\t\t";
echo $email;
echo "\n\n";
```

**to**

```
echo "<tr><td>$id</td><td>$name</td><td>$email</td></tr>;
```

And call the function before the close of the table.
 And also, you have an extra  < /tr> before closing the body tag

```
</tr></tbody>
```

Comment: not working for me,it is only printing all the records in a single line

Comment: Don't you want to display all the records?

Comment: Yes i want to display all the records but in the table,no matter what i try it only displaying me all the records in one line

Answer (score 0):

So why don't you built your table generic with PHP? As much as I can see you are not doing a AJAX-Request or something like that.

something like:

```
function table()
{
    $client2 = new client2();
    if (isset($_POST['btn-signup'])) 
    {  
        try
        {   
            $results=$client2->allClients();

            foreach(array ($results) as $row) 
            {
                echo '<tr>';  
                echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['email'] . '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';

            }

        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}


/* Set this line where your static rows now are */
<table id="data-table-command" class="table table-striped table-vmiddle">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th data-column-id="id" data-type="numeric">ID</th>
                                <th data-column-id="sender">Sender</th>
                                <th data-column-id="received" data-order="desc">Received</th>
                                <th data-column-id="commands" data-formatter="commands" data-sortable="false">Commands</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                           <?php table(); ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but even this is not working it is only showing me a single line in which all records are printed.

Comment: Just inspect it in the browser, maybe is any tag missing which makes the table incomplete. But if all the data is given from the query, it's on the client-side-layer. Maybe just also try to give the table a border so you can see where it is going wrong. Because all the given answers here should work. I wonder how your css looks like for that table..

Comment: I ll keep in mind all your suggestions...I hope it works now...thank you for your time and efforts

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the function,this is the correct code.It's now working perfectly

```
public function allClients()//function 
    {
        try
        {
            $stmt = $this->conn->query("SELECT * FROM client");
            $stmt->execute();
            $results = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $stmt;

        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Function call

```
 <table id="data-table-command" class="table table-striped table-vmiddle">
                         <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th data-column-id="id" data-type="numeric">ID</th>
                                <th data-column-id="sender">Sender</th>
                                <th data-column-id="received" data-order="desc">Received</th>
                                <th data-column-id="commands" data-formatter="commands" data-sortable="false">Commands</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php

                            $results=$client2->allClients();

                            foreach($results as $row){
                                echo "<tr><td>".$row['id']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['username']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['whatphn']."</td>";
                            //  echo "<td>".$row['email']."</td></tr>";

                            }
                        ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```